# Suppress non-exhaustive match warning from let using list

Tags: ocaml

In OCaml, you can define variables `x` and `y` within a list as follows, but you get a warning:

```
let [x; y] = [2; 3];;
Characters 4-10:
Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a case that is not matched:
(_::_::_::_|_::[]|[])
```

(In my real code I have a function that returns a list of values.  Sometimes I know that it will only return two values.)

I know how to suppress the warning when using `match` or `function` by adding a catch-all case, as explained in answers to the questions listed below.  What's the best way to suppress the warning when I'm defining using a list as above?

[this pattern-matching is not exhaustive in OCaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737031/this-pattern-matching-is-not-exhaustive-in-ocaml)

[Suppress exhaustive matching warning in OCaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119290/suppress-exhaustive-matching-warning-in-ocaml)

Comment: maybe let (x, y) = List.(nth l 0, nth l 1) where l is the return value of your function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a catch-all case as in

```
let (x,y) = match [2;3] with
  | [x;y] -> (x,y)
  | _ -> assert false (* how could this list not have exactly 2 elements?*)
```

is probably not a bad idea, since it gives you space to comment on why you expect only the first pattern. That said, if you really insist on using `let`, you can use [attributes](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/extn.html#sec246) to temporarily disable a warning, as in:

```
[@@@ warning "-8"]
(* My list is guaranteed to have two elements. disable warning for a while. *)
let [x;y] = [2;3];;
[@@@ warning "+8"]
```

Comment: Thanks Virtile.  I don't like using attributes, which I didn't know anything about and which seems extreme, but in context adding the `match` just to parse the values of a list (which really can only have two values) makes the code hard to understand.  I can imagine coming back to it in six months, thinking *why??* do I have a match here?  (OK, I'd comment it, but still.)  The attributes method can't be confused with code that has a real purpose. :-)